# How to filter array of fields on React-redux-firefbase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am looking for a way to fetch some docs which contain some values of an array  (e.g.)"stack" or "flow"
However, my code below didn't get any records.

```es
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),firestoreConnect([{ 
    collection : 'projects', 
    where:["tags", "array-contains-any", ["stack"]], 
    orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc'] 
  }])
)(Board);
```

I refer to this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

[image]

I found out when I changed the code. It works and shows the projects.
But I reloaded the browser the project was gone.
I also found that the parameters of firestoreConnect is less than 4, it wotks even if the page is refreshed.

Is there any alternative way?

```
//This code works anytime.
firestoreConnect([{ 
    collection : 'projects', 
    where:["tags", "array-contains-any", ["stack"]], 
    orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc'] 
  }])
```

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

  render() {
    const { projects  } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="dashboard container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 m6">
            <ProjectList projects = {projects }/>
          </div>
          <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
            <Notifications />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your object inside the `firestoreConnect` is malformed

Comment: Where is deformed?

Comment: now, its not. after the edit.